# How to horizontally center HTML using parent element only?

Tags: css, centering

Is there a way to center some HTML by only using a parent wrapper element? The parent wrapper element cannot reference the `width` of the `innerHTML`. The only way I can do it is with the `<center>` tag, but as we know `<center>` is outdated. For example, to `center` this:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#ff0000;"></div>
```

this:

```
<div style="width:800px;height:100px;background-color:#ff0000;"></div>
```

this:

```
<p>a little text here</p>
```

or this:

```
<p style="width:400px;">a lot of text here fjskdfj sldjf slkdfj skldjf ksdjf kdsfj ksdjf skdfj ksdjf ksdjf ksdjf ksdjf ksdjf skdjf ksdjf skdfj skdfj ksdjf skdjf ksdjf ksdfj skdfj skdfj skdfj</p>
```

I can simply wrap them with `<center>` and it works. But is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Centering with **css**

```
html code:

<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
      <p>A lot of text here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
.parent {
   width:800px;
}

.parent .center {
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and the `<div>` with class `center` will be aligned in the center.

Comment: not what i'm looking for. i want the parent element to do the centering. here you are having the inner element do the centering. when i use `<center>` as the parent element it is doing the centering.

Comment: @Ryan what does this mean, "the parent does the centering". are just trying to center the text?

Comment: i want to center arbitrary HTML using only a parent wrapper element to do the centering. when i use just `<center></center>` as the parent wrapper element it works and i don't have to use `margin:0 auto` on the inner elements. it also works for both inline and block elements. but is there a way to do that without using `<center>`?

Comment: In this method the child element is centered in relation to the parent. and using margin is the alternative to using the `center` tag

Answer (score 0):

Define `text-align` property for the **parent** like this: `text-align: center;`

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: center` on your `parent` element.